# Quartic Casimir of the 3D conformal group

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, invariants

I am studying the conformal group in 3 dimensions. The generators of this group are isomorphic to the generators of $SO(1,4)$. Hence two of the Casimir operators are,

$$C_1=-\tfrac12J_{AB}J^{AB}$$

$$C_2=-(\tfrac18\epsilon^{ABCDE}J_{BC}J_{DE})^2$$

It's easy to calculate the eigenvalues of the quadratic Casimir on primary states. However, how do you calculate the eigenvalues of the second?